# Extract value from task in Swift 3

Tags: swift

I have a problem when trying to parse a simple website in Swift 3. I combined what I found on this website, but still can't extract loginText from the other function, and got a 'instance member can't be used on .. type' error when trying to put everything into a class.

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
extension String {

    func slice(from: String, to: String) -> String? {

        return (range(of: from)?.upperBound).flatMap { substringFrom in
            (range(of: to, range: substringFrom..<endIndex)?.lowerBound).map { substringTo in
                substring(with: substringFrom..<substringTo)
            }
        }
    }
}


var loginText = ""


func getToken(completionHandler: (String) -> () ) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: [MY URL])!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    var loginText = ""

    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, err in
        loginText = (String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    }
    task.resume()
}


func viewDidLoad() {
    getToken {
        loginText in
        loginText.slice(from: "LT", to: "1s1")
        print("View Controller: \(loginText)")
    }
}

print(viewDidLoad())
print(loginText)
```

Thanks !

Comment: You are not even calling `completionHandler` in the task's completion handler. At where exactly does the error happen? Please elaborate your question with these issues addressed.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I have to admit that I really am not understanding a lot of what I am doing at the moment. I am just trying to achieve what I was doing in python, using requests, and the thing you see here is the result of 3 hours of trial and manly error. All I am trying to do is to get the loginText, to be able to use it outside of getToken().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got you.

You are coincidentally using the wrong loginText.

You called the completionHandler string loginText while also having loginText declared outside the function.

But you were on the right path.

Your problem will be solved if you call self.loginText, check this out:

```
 getToken {
    loginText in //you named it loginText
    self.loginText.slice(from: "LT", to: "1s1")
    print("View Controller: \(loginText)")
}
```

The thing is, this STILL never gets called. Because you are never calling that completionHandler, also - 
forget about self.loginText, because you have a completionHandler that just passes your string.

Use this and don't even change the getToken method. It will be called, and will work fine:

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, err in
    let loginText = (String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    completionHandler(loginText)
}
```

Also I would delete the `var loginText = ""` if you don't want to use it outside of getToken. But even if you are, I would suggest just having a function which takes in a `String`, rather then having it declared just outside. But you know why you need it outside if you do - so yeah. Cheers

EDIT:  You also seem to be missing the `@escaping`

```
func getToken(completionHandler: @escaping (String) -> () ) {}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I however get a 

error: closure use of non-escaping parameter 'completionHandler' may allow it to escape

When using the completionHandler as suggested...

Comment: Are you using swift 3?

Comment: Yes ! I just solved the issue by adding @espacing inside the completion handler. Thank you !

Comment: Yeah I just edited my answer to include that :) . If you could mark question as correct that would be awesome ;)

Comment: However, how could I get viewDidLoad() to return 'textLogin' ?

Comment: Your getToken has a completion handler. Are you in playground file? Then just have the viewDidLoad also have a completion handler same as getToken. Otherwise viewDidLoad can't have a return type. Also: the whole point of completion handlers is against having returns. You cannot have a return type if you are waiting for backends response. That's why there's a completion handler. When it gets executed you will have the return in its closure. Just remove the print around viewDidLoad()